# Changing table from tableviewcontroller to regular view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Sorry if this kind of question isn't welcome here but I'd appreciate the help. I have a fully functioning table now set up but I did it using the TableViewController in storyboard. I now realize I cannot change the size of the view using that item and it doesn't fit well on the screen as is. I understand I need to use a regular view controller and add the table view manually. I can do that but I spent hours getting the table to work properly and I'm afraid to break it. Can someone walk me through transitioning between the two?

Here is the [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc5bj.png)

Here is the view controller code

```
import UIKit

class CharacterTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var characterTableView: UITableView!

    var characterArray: [Character] = [Character]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.characterSetup()
    }

    func characterSetup() {

        var admiralSwiggins = Character(name: "Admiral Swiggins", abilities: "Stun, Blind, Shield, Damage Over Time, Area of Effect", characterImage: "admiral.png")
        var ayla = Character(name: "Ayla", abilities: "Area of Effect, Damage Over Time, Fly, Lifesteal, Shield, Slow", characterImage: "ayla.png")
        var clunk = Character(name: "Clunk", abilities: "Lifesteal, Area of effect, Ensnare, Slow, Launch String", characterImage: "clunk.png")

        characterArray.append(admiralSwiggins)
        characterArray.append(ayla)
        characterArray.append(clunk)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:CharacterTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CharacterTableViewCell

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }

        let character = characterArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = character.name
        cell.abilityLabel.text = character.abilities
        cell.characterImage.image = UIImage(named: character.characterImage)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    }
}
```

And here is the cell

```
import UIKit

class CharacterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var abilityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var characterImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: @codester I'm sorry. I haven't attempted to make the transition yet because I'm sure I'll break it. I was just looking to see if someone could provide a short list of steps in order to switch from the two while keeping everything intact. Sorry if stupid question but I'm a novice.

Comment: You should set your project up with Git. This way you won't have to worry about breaking things & being unable to go back. Changed my life when I discovered it ;)